# dialogflow nodejs function returning empty object instead of string

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have been trying to create a function to get the right response from dialogflow, however, my function kept returning an empty object despite the console.log returning the right replies, have been stuck on this for quite some time and was wondering where I could have done wrong.

TLDR my function is not returning the string, instead returning an empty object.

```
async function getIntent(projectId,sessionId,query, languageCode='en'){

  const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
      keyFileName:"../service-account.json"
  });
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: query,
        languageCode: languageCode,
      },
    },
  };
  const response = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  console.log(response[0].queryResult.fulfillmentText)
  return response[0].queryResult.fulfillmentText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say that the `console.log` statement in the snippet correctly outputs the intended value, I assume the problem is on how you consume the `getIntent` function.

```js
async function main () {
  const intent = await getIntent(…)
  …
}

main().catch(console.error)
```

Here, the `main` function needs to `await` the result of the `getIntent` call which is asynchronous. If you don't use this keyword, intent will be an empty promise, not the value inside.